# Lorentz Group and Metric Differences

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, group-theory, mathematics

I've been studying the Lorentz and Poincare Groups for about a week and one thing that got me thinking is how different materials tend to use different metrics and this triggers me on how this could possibly change the results (if it changes them of course) and if different metrics imply in different derivations on the group, its properties and so on.

For example, some materials use $\eta = \textrm{diag}(+1, -1, -1, -1)$ and some use $\eta = \textrm{diag}(-1, +1, +1, +1)$.

Comment: It is purely a matter of convention, it has no physical significance

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668792/11127) Math.SE post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference appears on the sign of some quantities, because the difference between one and the other is that of a multiplying by $-1$ on both sides. Some quantities whose signs are different are:

- Energy/distance
- spacelike/timelike spacetime measures

Basically, the results don't change.

The reason some textbooks use one or the other is individual preference of the author. Some times a community of physicists will use the convention that better fits the results they obtain (usually for them not to be negative). Particle physicists like the energy to be positive, hence $\eta = \text{diag}(+,-,-,-)$, since energy relates to time. Cosmologists like that their distances are positive, hence $\eta = \text{diag}(-,+,+,+)$.